# How to get unique value from sql table based on charachter length of value

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Here I have two columns like below example column1 & column2 in sql table and i want to get unique value row on the basis of **column2** column value from table 

Below example of dummy table

```
 Column1             Column2

----------         -------------

 1001                   ab
 1001                   abc
 1001                   abcd
 2001                   wxyz
 2001                   wxy
 2001                   wx
```

In above example value starting from **a** & another value starting from **w** in **Column2** 

On the basis of same value character length, i want to get result like below 

**Output**:

```
 Column1                Column2

----------           -----------

1001                     abcd
2001                     wxyz
```

Thanks in advance of help :)

Comment: Describe how to pick column2 value, for a unique column1 value.

Comment: above output based on column2 value (charachter length) on single table columns

Comment: What if two rows have different values, but  the same (max) length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking if your values in column2 are somewhere included in other rows, in other words: If you are looking for rows with combinations of characters which are unique on their own, this might be your solution:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(Column1 INT,Column2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES
 (1001,'ab')
,(1001,'abc')
,(1001,'abcd')
,(2001,'wxyz')
,(2001,'xyz')
,(2001,'yz');

SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM TestTable AS x 
                 WHERE x.Column1=TestTable.Column1 
                   AND LEN(x.Column2)>LEN(TestTable.Column2)
                   AND x.Column2 LIKE  '%' + TestTable.Column2  + '%'
                )

DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

Comment: -- AND x.Column2 LIKE  '%' + TestTable.Column2  + '%' Comment this line & thanks for above query.

Comment: @Pankaj, glad that this could help you... Please - for the next time you ask something - keep in mind, that **other users do not know what is clear to you**. Please provide sample data, expected output, clear description, correct tags (DBMS!) and what you've tried yourself and what errors / wrong results you've got with this. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want the highest length (you didn't say what to do when there are two with the same length) but basically you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE (column1,len(column2)) IN(select Column1,max(len(column2))
                                FROM YourTable
                                GROUP BY Column1)
```

Comment: But this will just search for the greatest length not looking at the content of the text. Now it's you who was to fast probably and jarlh asked the right question in his comment :-)

Comment: Yes, but I checked the content of the data, abcd is greater then ab, and wxyz is smaller then xyz,yz , so the only thing that I could make sense of it, is to pick the one with the max length:) @Shnugo

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: As the OP -maybe - was interested in the length only, I'll give you an upvote for your guessing abilities :-)